# Rstudio renders in console, but errors when outputting to HTML in markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am attempting to output some graphics to HTML using Rstudio RMarkdown, and it just seems there is a user error that I can't figure. The dataaset was imported, and I am able to call the rows which are printed in the console. However, When i try to use the "knit" funsction, I am met with an error and It can not render. **Running the code chunk works in the console**

```
Metric <- (Metrics$`Metrics`)
Freq <- (Metrics$`Frequency`)
```

the errorcode I get is

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'Metrics" not found Calls <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> eval -> eval execution halted
```

**I am a newbie to R and it could just be something small I am missing.

Comment: In the code you’ve shown, there’s no need to backtick-quote the identifiers, and it’s odd to do so. (It’s akin to putting parentheses around every identifier, or `+` in front of every number … it’s mostly valid, but useless).

Comment: Interesting. That explains it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it would be hard to say without seeing the whole code but my guess is that you don't start the Metrics object in your Rmarkdown. Meaning, you have it in your globao environment (which explains why it runs when you just run the chunk) but once you knit it it just cant find it.
You should be creating the Metrics object explicitly in rmarkdown for it to be able to use it and knit it. Hope that helps.

Comment: How would I go about that? do you mean instead od using the import gui code it direclty in and pass it in?

Comment: Exactly. The assignment you do for thst object for you to have it on your global environment should be included in the rmarkdown code as it is. So in your chunk, before you call for columns in it, assign it whatever that is and that should be working.

Comment: great input my friend. I guess i just got lazy and didnt try this. worked just fine.